# Wiremock stubbing error: "Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock, stubbing, jsonexception

here I come because I have not found any solution to my problem. I'm actually trying to stub a response with wiremock (that call to the Mocked service is be done via FeignClient). My intention is to get a fake response with the real feign client, not in a test, but in the real application. Therefore, In this case, I'm not stubbing the WireMockServer in a test, but in the spring boot application class, however when stubbing there the response I'm having a super weird error that I have investigated a lot so far without success.

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrmApplication
      implements CommandLineRunner
{
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    public CrmApplication( ConfigurableApplicationContext context )
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        log.info( "Starting the CRM Validator" );
        SpringApplication.run( CrmApplication.class, args );
        log.info( "Finishing the CRM Validator" );
    }

    @Override
    public void run( String... args )
    {
        final WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer( options().port( 8000 ) );
        server.start();
        log.info( "Wiremock has started in the following url: {}", "http://localhost:8000\n\n" );

        String resultJson = "{\"id\":1,\"hasJudicialRecords\":false}";

        MappingBuilder mappingBuilder = get( urlPathEqualTo( "/api/v1/judicial-registry/1") )
              .willReturn( aResponse().withStatus( 200 )
                                      .withHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" )
                                      .withBody( resultJson ) )
        stubFor( mappingBuilder );

    }
}
```

This is actually failing in the `stubFor( mappingBuilder );` line, and this is the exception I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:822) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:803) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:346) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.crm.demo.CrmApplication.main(CrmApplication.java:31) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
Caused by: com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException: {
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/timestamp"
    },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unrecognized field \"timestamp\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"
  } ]
}
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException.fromJackson(JsonException.java:53) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Json.read(Json.java:55) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.safelyExecuteRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:486) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:454) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:131) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:298) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:293) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:104) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.java:108) ~[wiremock-jre8-2.28.0.jar:na]
    at com.crm.demo.CrmApplication.run(CrmApplication.java:31) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:819) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

So one question would be, does wiremock only work in testing?

I have tried changing the JSON, and its fields but that does not seem to work, so if any of you know whow to solve that issue would be helpful, or if you also know how to stub an api request  that is called by @FeignClient (not in a test but in the real spring application run) as an alternative maybe could work too.

Thank you!.

Comment: This is very strange behaviour. There's no reason it shouldn't be possible to run WireMock alongside your production Spring app - I've seen it done quite a few times before. One hypotheses is that another dependency is changing the Jackson configuration somehow at the global scope. If this is the case, switching to the standalone JAR might stop it happening (since Jackson is shaded in that one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after `server.start()` you need:

```
configureFor("localhost", server.port());
```

Comment: Or just `configureFor(server.port());`